# club json values together and create a csv

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have a json data that i would like to club and create a csv file thereafter. The json data looks like below. The data will not be the same always (like in first json object there are only two fields while in second and third there are 3 fields but some of these are different, actually, the data is form input and can be dynamic based on the input received on non-mandatory elements).
The thing i am sure of is that only one JSON array will contain all the json

```
[{"firstName":"Kukreja","lastName":"Ramesh"},{"firstName":"Ram","lastName":"Laxman","dob":"jan-1990"},{"firstName":"Sam","resourceType":"/dmp/formdata","lastName":"Paul"}]
```

I have to create a spreadsheet with this data. So the column heading should say firstName and all the json object values like kureja/Ram/Sam should appear in separate rows other data should be formatted accordingly in columns and rows.

Currently, i am using this function to create a csv

```
function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {

    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','
            console.log(array[i][index]);
            line += array[i][index];
        }

        str += line + '\r\n';
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It is as simple as creating a CSV using the json data i have as input but json data will be dynamic and csv columns should capture the data accordingly in row and column format

Comment: I understand that's what you're trying to do; does the code you posted not do that? What is the difficulty you are experiencing?

Comment: the issue i am experiencing is if the ordering at json end is different for different objects then csv getting generated does not captures that correctly and categorization according to field type is not happening and i am not sure how can i put only one header at the top of csv which should say firstName, lastName etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the function below...

**FIXED EXAMPLE!.... please see again**

see the example! -> http://jsfiddle.net/Castrolol/9m9W5/
in the example have a download metho too...

```
function json2csv(objArray, headers, showHeaders) {

    if( typeof headers == "boolean" ){
         showHeaders = headers;
        headers = null;
    }

    var itens = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

    //separate fields 
    var fields = {};

    if( !headers ){
        for(var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++){         
            for(var prop in itens[i]){             
                if( !fields[prop] ){                 
                    fields[prop] = [];                    
                }                
            }            
        }
    }else{
        headers.forEach(function(header){ fields[header] = []; });
    }


    //getting data

    for(var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++){        
        for(var prop in fields){            
            if( typeof itens[i][prop] != "undefined" ){
                fields[prop].push( itens[i][prop] );
            }else{
                fields[prop].push( "" );
            }            
        }        
    }

    //make the csv

    var csvLines = [];

    if( showHeaders ){

        var lineFields = [];

        for(var prop in fields){            
            lineFields.push(  prop );                        
        }

        var line = lineFields.join(", ");
        csvLines.push(line);        

    }

    for(var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++){

        var lineFields = [];

        for(var prop in fields){            
            lineFields.push(  fields[prop][i] );                        
        }

        var line = lineFields.join(", ");
        csvLines.push(line);        
    }

    var csvStr = "sep=,\n" + csvLines.join("\n");    

    return csvStr;
}
```

Comment: What you have provided works, but i see that i have to provide the headers explicitly, can this be picked from the json itself but again the json object might be different. Also, i want the headers to come in csv and below that the data should come. With the code you have provided only the data is getting exported.

Comment: if you not provide the headers 'll pick from json dynamically, with 3 lines you put the headers, i'll modify to you...

Comment: It seems to work. Sine i am out of office now, will integrate the JS later and will update again. thanks a ton mate :)